# Is there any difference between "time line" and "timeline"?

Tags: compound-nouns

Whenever I type "timeline," without a space, it gets red squiggly line. But when I search to Google, the word actually exists. Is there any difference? And please give some other compound words that can be written in many ways? Adding a dash and a space and without any.

Comment: Don't trust automatic grammar or spelling checkers very much, they're not very good.

Answer (score 2):

`Timeline` means the linear portrayal of chronological events. `Time line` is incorrect in this context (although I suppose the words could show up in some other sentence with an unrelated meaning, e.g., "the runner crossed the time line").

`in to` and `into` are commonly confused as well, since the word `in` is used last in so many two-word idiomatic phrases.  Explanation: http://writingexplained.org/into-vs-in-to-difference

Answer (score 2):

Based on an article at [The MLA Style Center](https://style.mla.org/dictionary-101/) (which uses definitions from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timeline)), a "time line" is a dated list of significant events that have happened in the past, while a "timeline" is a schedule or timetable of planned events.